# Android: ANR Input dispatching timed out

Tags: android, performance

I am getting following error logs on some phone which as follow:

Reason: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length: 20.  Wait queue head age: 5509.1ms.)

I am using Retrofit 2 for networking calls in which I use async method, Using database as realm where I used async transaction for writing stuff.
Using Glide for image loading.

On using Strict Mode I found out I get penalty log for shared preferences nothing else. Any other pointers to see and debug issue

Answer (score 1):

Any types of time expensive procedure like data syncing through network shouldn't do in `main thread`. `Android` has some default built-in methods like `AsyncTask`, `IntentService` etc. those are on `worker thread`. Personally I have not good idea about Retrofit 2. If it works on `main thread`, that case you should use it in a separate thread.

Comment: according to documentation retrofit 2 enqueue method works in async.

Comment: @jitenshah Yes I was able to Solve it. Actually I was doing my db operation of writing on main thread which was heavy moved it to async task it worked like a charm. Using realm as database in android

Comment: for me it was gms module.